# One other session at postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I'm using rspec to test. I was working on a project with my friend on his laptop and tests were passing. I cloned the repo and running it on my laptop and all test are failing all of sudden.

so I decided to reset the test database. I called `rake db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV=test`. Then, I started getting an error saying:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "(app name)" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

I looked into other stackoverflow posts and found that I can kill the connection using

> sudo kill -9 `ps -u postgres -o pid=`

And this successfully kills something and gives me the result on the console like following:

```
usage: kill [-s signal_name] pid ...
       kill -l [exit_status]
       kill -signal_name pid ...
       kill -signal_number pid ...
```

Am I doing this correctly? How do I successfully delete the other session?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the kill command you're running is actually terminating anything. I also wouldn't recommend killing any of the postgres processes directly as this might be unsafe.

Instead try running `ps aux | grep ruby` or `ps aux | grep rspec` It's possible that a ruby or rspec process is still running without your knowledge. From there you can get the process id (pid) of that process and kill it using `kill -15 <pid>`. If it still doesn't stop, use `kill -9 <pid>` to force it to quit.